# What are the pros and cons of a directive based programming model?

Tags: c++, openmp, pragma, sycl

What are the pros and cons of a directive based programming model?

Taking for instance a programming model like OpenMP, what are the disadvantages and advantages you get when using a directive based programming framework like this over one like SYCL which is explicit.

Comment: List type questions are off topic on stackoverflow. [Are list questions off topic?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139618/are-list-questions-off-topic). **Be specific about the question.**

Comment: While this question is rather opinion-based, few quite objective points include the following. 1. Some transformation are possible with directive (and more generally annotations) that are not possible with libraries and API. For example SIMD transformations. There are API for that but they are low-level and manual because they cannot impact the compiler itself (not more than what the language permit). 2. API/libraries tends to be more flexible (better integration with the language -- e.g. templates in C++ for OMP) and easier to maintain (because it is not implemented within a compiler).

Comment: Then comes factors like readability, ease of use, etc. which are pretty subjective (opinion-based and off topic here.