# OpenMP & oneTbb difference

Tags: c++, multithreading, openmp, tbb, intel-oneapi

My program utilizes a 'for' loop parallelized with two methods: OpenMP and oneTBB, with oneTBB executing faster.

What's the difference between OpenMP and oneTBB at a low level (memory organization, thread creation, cache)?

I use a parallel 'for' loop in the Gauss algorithm, and regardless of the matrix size, oneTBB executes faster than OpenMP.

Comment: This is close to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78251954/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-a-directive-based-programming-model) created 15 min ago. My comment applies for OMP vs TBB. Note this is also quite opinion based too.

Comment: Regarding performance, OpenMP is a *specification*, so there is no 1 OpenMP implementation but many. 2 mainstream ones are maintained (GOMP and IOMP). They often behave pretty differently performance wise. It is often difficult to tell whether the implementation is the problem or the specification itself. TBB is an API tightly related to its unique implementation. Thus, you need to provide which implementation do you use (i.e. which compiler). The exact directives and clauses matter a lot for performance, especially the scheduling used. Please *share the code*.